# RevMob full screen ads not going away, iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, fullscreen, revmob

Hy there,

We have an application that is live and has numerous user world wide. We have added revmob few years ago, everything was fine in all that time, but recently various users from USA are complaining that full screens ads pop ups are not removing. and some users mentioned that there are various pop ups displayed. Some of them mentioned that there is no close button to hide the pop up.

We tested here with us, check others countries feedbacks no one complains about it.... All those users that faces this issue are from USA.

We are in a bit trouble. and thinking to remove and not to use ads any more. but if you people has any idea or any solution for that, please let us know asap.

here is my code I call to display ads:

```
RevMobFullscreen *fs = [[RevMobAds session] fullscreen];
fs.delegate = self;
[fs showAd];
```

Thanks